# What are Koszul dualities?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, higher-category-theory, koszul-duality

I am bewildered by the number of things I've heard referred to as "Koszul duality", and I would like to sort it out. At various different times, I believe I've seen any of the following phenomena referred to as "Koszul duality":

1. Let $O$ be an operad (in your favorite symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category $\mathcal V$), and apply the operadic bar construction to $O$ (i.e. regard $O$ as a monoid in symmetric sequences equipped with Kelly's convolution monoidal product $\circ$, and take the the geometric realization of the simplicial symmetric sequence $[n] \mapsto O^{\circ n}$) to obtain $BO$. Then (under certain conditions?) $BO$ is a cooperad, called the *Koszul dual* of $O$. Dually, if $C$ is a cooperad, then applying the operadic cobar construction to $C$ yields an operad called the *Koszul dual* of $C$. Under certain conditions, these constructions are adjoint to one another, and under certain further conditions they are inverse to one another.
2. There is a version of (1) called *Koszul duality* carrying $O$-modules to $BO$-comodules (and maybe a variant carrying $O$-algebras to $BO$-coalgebras?).
3. Let $O$ be the $E_k$ operad, and let $A$ be an $O$-algebra. Then there is an iterated bar-construction carrying $A$ to an $E_k$-coalgebra, which is called its *Koszul dual*.
4. Let $O$ be a quadratic operad in the sense of Ginzburg and Kapranov (quadratic-ness only makes sense in certain $\mathcal V$ -- basically $V$ must be chain complexes). Then there is another quadratic operad *Koszul dual* to $O$, and if $O$ is *Koszul*, then the duality operation is self-inverse at $O$.
5. There is also *Koszul duality* for algebras for the associative operad.
6. I think I've been told that the $E_k$-operad is *Koszul self-dual*. Since the $E_k$-operad makes sense in spaces, where quadraticness isn't even defined, I don't know what this means (I only know what it means for an operad to be dual to a coopeard in this generality, following (1)).

I *think* what's going on is that the fundamental duality is the bar/cobar adjunction between operads $O$ and cooperads $BO$; duality between $O$-modules and $BO$-comodules, and between $O$-algebras and $BO$-coalgebras then comes along for the ride. Then some other form of duality sometimes allows one to relate cooperads back to operads, and we start talking about duality between operads, and between the modules / algebras for an operad and its dual operad from there. But I've never really seen this spelled out in this general a context.

**Question:** What is the relationship between the above things called *Koszul duality* (and other things called *Koszul duality* which I'm missing)?

I hope it's clear that this question has a different focus from [this classic MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/329/what-is-koszul-duality).

Comment: Your broad picture is essentially correct.  It's tough to write a full answer, because there are technicalities that make it hard to say what the "correct" general setting is.  To say something like $E_k$ is self dual, you $\mathcal V$ to be stable and have duals so that you can dualize a co-operad and make it into an operad.

Comment: I like think about Koszul duality as "exchanging the forget/free adjunction for O with the square-zero/cotangent complex adjunction for the Koszul dual O^". For instance, if k = char 0, then the cotangent complex/bar construction of a free commutative algebra on a (perfect, say) k-module V is the dual V* with the "trivial" Lie structure. You can similarly calculate the cotangent complex of a square-zero extension k (+) V to be the free Lie algebra on V*. In a precise sense, establishing such equivalences is the main technical content of Koszul duality.

Comment: I should add that much of the power Koszul duality as practiced by representation theorists (and originally by Priddy) comes from *model dependent* formulations.  From an general perspective, every operad with operations of arity $\geq 2$ has a "Koszul dual"--given by a bar construction.   But for quadratic operads there is a much smaller co-operad, defined in terms of the presentation, which is often quasi-isomorphic to the one you get from the bar construction. A representation theorist would say that the original operad is Koszul only when this small model agrees with the bar construction.

Comment: From this point of view, Koszul duality is concerned with constructing small models for Bar constructions.  As a special case, this theory contains the fact that you can use the Koszul complex to compute Tor groups for modules over a polynomial ring.   I'd recommend Loday and Valette's book Algebraic Operads for more on this

Comment: @PhilTosteson Thanks, this is enlightening. One thing that still confuses me is that in Higher Algebra Ch 5.2 Lurie discusses a notion of Koszul duality for E_k algebras which seems to be the composite of the bar/cobar duality and some other form of duality, but this second form is not simply dualization in a monoidal category as far as I can see, and I _think_ this is related to some nonabelian sense in which the E_k operad is "Koszul self-dual". The point about model-dependency is well-taken.

Comment: Ah, yes you're right.  I take back that you need stability to talk about duality between the $E_n$'s.  I'm not really sure what the right level of generality is-- or really if there is one. As you make more assumptions you probably get more features/simplifications.

Comment: One way to think about this is that everything is a special case of 5. One model for Infinity operads are E_1 algebras in symmetric sequences, E_1 KD in that case gives you operad KD. E_n KD is an iterated version of the E_1 case as explained in HA, but can also be gotten from the E_n self-duality. Statements about modules tend to be some Morita theory using that the underlying module of the koszul dual looks like an endomorphism algebra

Comment: Also potentially confusing is that for an algebra you can talk about a KD algebra OR a KD coalgebra (regarding your comment about E_n self-duality), they’re variants of the same construction, at the level of underlying objects they’re related by linear duality. These are explained respectively in 5.2.2 and 5.2.5 of HA.

Comment: Of course one can imagine turning this on its head and take operadic KD to be more fundamental, prove E_n self duality somehow, then deduce E_1 KD - maybe there exists a language where this path is convenient, my perspective is coming from someone more comfortable at thinking about E_1 algebras than at operadic homological algebra

Answer (score 5):

I have finally found a source which puts together the pieces in a satisfactory way, at least in the stable setting, here:

Amabel, Araminta. "Poincaré/Koszul Duality for General Operads." arXiv preprint arXiv:1910.09076 (2019). [latest arxiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.09076).

- Amabel discusses (see Thm 2.20) Koszul duality of operads and cooperads in spectra (Ching has [shown](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.5034) that the bar/cobar adjunction for spectral operads / cooperads is an equivalence here with no conditions!!! This is very surprising to me given that most authors assume very very restrictive conditions like being a quadratic operad to get similar results.)
- Amabel also discusses (see Thm 2.21) the relationship between Koszul duality for operads and cooperads, and the induced bar/cobar adjunctions for the (ind,nilpotent,with divided powers co)/algebras of the corresponding co/operads, with reference to [Francis-Gaitsgory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.5803) and [Ching's thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501429). According to [Ching and Harper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.06944), this bar adjunction is also an equivalence if you assume only that the operad is connective -- which again seems like a much weaker assumption than I expected!
- Lots more good stuff in here...